# Partial String Matching with Python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to compare some text to a pre-built list of words, specifically vehicle manufacturers. The problem is that the text I am comparing is written by humans and is not always reliable.

For example, I want to find "Harley Davidson" but the text actually says "Hardley Davidson" or some other careless typo.

I don't think I can use regex to solve this problem... or can I?
Is there a partial string matching function? Maybe I could define a percentage of the string that must match.

Comment: http://streamhacker.com/2011/10/31/fuzzy-string-matching-python/ you should find nltk  useful

Comment: That looks like a good option. Haven't seen it before. Trying now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy) module

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
fuzz.partial_ratio("Harley Davidson","Hardley Davidson")
93
```

For more on fuzzy wuzzy and it's method try this [link](http://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/)

Comment: Looks good. Do you have enough experience with it to know a decent ratio to use as a threshold? 75% is probably what I would start with.

Comment: @WilliamKeidel there are many method see the second link and choose a appropriate method then think about threshold

Answer (score 0):

It is called edit distance : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance
You can do it by using NLTK or Levensthein
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/

Here is an example using Levenshtein (which is faster than the nltk edit_distance function), you first have ton install the library (link provided):

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import Levenshtein

mylist = ["harley davidson", "kawazaki"]

for element in mylist:
    if Levenshtein.distance(element.lower(), "Hardley Davidson".lower()) == 1:
        print("same word with mispelling")
```

btw :

- i lowered case everything here you can do it or not
- you can but a greater distance than one if mispellings are multiples